# Error on installing the tidyverse and ggplot2 packages

Tags: r.net

I am seeing the following error when trying to install the `tidyverse` and `ggplot2` R package

`Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'C:/Users/dell user/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/filebad038967c5e/rlang/help/figures/rlang.png': Permission denied`.

How can I go around this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the path where you install them is restricted. To fix this issue:

1. Run the RStudio as Administrator. If this doesn't fix it:
2. Sometimes `Windows Defender Ransomware Protection` can cause issues. Add `rsession.exe` as an exception.
3. Change the R library folder (where your packages get installed) to a folder you have access to, like somewhere in your own Documents or Desktop or another path you control.